# Interpolate bash command in Heroku scheduler

Tags: node.js, bash, heroku

How can I interpolate a bash command in a Heroku scheduler command?

I have a command that runs everyday & it takes a day. Now I want to make it dynamic using bash date command e.g

```
cli "$(date --date "7 day ago")"
```

For today it will be `Sat Apr 27 22:36:46 +06 2019` and for tomorrow it will be `Sun Apr 28 22:36:46 +06 2019`.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Stack Overflow's syntax highlighting makes the problem pretty clear. You're nesting double quotes inside double quotes without escaping them:

```
cli "$(date --date "7 day ago")"
```

This is interpreted as three arguments:

- `"$(date --date "7`
- `day`
- `ago")"`

Replace the innner ones with single quotes and it should work:

```
cli "$(date --date '7 day ago')"
```

Another alternative would be to escape the inner quotes with backslashes, but IMO using single quotes is more readable.